# Selenium Web-Driver Comparing data's in two different website using java

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Please can anyone help with a method that can compare/validate data's from two different website.

For example: I want to make sure that "Y" in the first URL is also showing "Y'' in URL two.

Apply for Application|  Submit| Close|
                   N |    Y   |  Y   |

---Data a in one www.sabak.com:- validate letter Y  if its the same thing in the second URL as Y

---Data b in second www.mandos.com:- validate letter "N"  if its the same thing in the second URL as "N"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go to the first page, read the values you want to compare into a list and then go to the next page and compare the values there against what's in the list:

```
//navigate to the first site and get the values you want to compare
    driver.navigate().to("www.sabak.com");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to element"));
    List<String> pageOneValues = new ArrayList<>();
    pageOneValues.add(element.getText());
// add more values to the list here as needed

// navigate to the next site and compare the values there with what's in the list
    driver.navigate().to("www.mandos.com");
    WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to element2"));
    Assert.assertEquals(pageOneValues.get(0), element2.getText());
// do more asserts here for the other values
```